# Working out which logic gates need to go where

Tags: logic-gates

I have something as below featuring XOR, AND, OR, XNOR, NAND and NOR gates. I have to get the bottom 3 outputs set to 1. As you can see, I've managed to do it as below but was wondering out of the 720 possible combinations, how many are there actually? Am I missing some logic myself or is there an online resource to help?

For the benefit of this, the inputs remain the same. Only the position of the gates can change.

[image]

Comment: Which *"720 possible combinations"*? Input combinations?

Comment: 6 gates as mentioned which is 6! combinations they can be in

Comment: There only 4 inputs.  So you only have to worry about 2^4=16 input possibilities.

Comment: The are 6 logic gates. Those inputs remain the same. The logic gates can be moved around. There's 6! combinations

Comment: Is this some sort of game, or something?

Comment: It was part of a challenge which you can see I successfully did bu the end 3 being lit up but it led me to ask the question, how many more are there and could this sort of thing be automated

Comment: for such a small example, even an exhaustive search would be trivial.

Comment: *"out of the 720 possible combinations, how many are there actually?"* 96. The hardest combinations of inputs and outputs have only 38 possible answers. The easiest ones, 160.  *"Am I missing some logic myself"* just search for all possible combinations using the programming language of your choice.

Comment: So there's no currently utility for this? Fine if so

Comment: @user_1818839 trivial? How so?

Comment: @pee2pee Simply create every combination and test it (in VHDL or a Python script or whatever).  If there were billions of combinations it wouldn't be trivial, of course, in terms of resources, but for fewer than a thousand...

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is use something called LogicFriday. By drawing out the circuit, the associated truth table can be generated to show all the combinations that meet the needed criteria

[image]

[image]

So there are 4 combinations which produce 0b111 output

Unfortunately the site did not renew the domain, but can still be found here:  https://web.archive.org/web/20131022021257/http://www.sontrak.com/

With 4 input's there is 16 combinations that need to be scanned, this is viable by hand

Comment: How would you do it for every combination of gate in the image/post?

Comment: For every combination of gates? Do you mean changing the physical gates or the inputs? Every combination of inputs is shown in the image within the truth table

Comment: Gates, hence the remark about 720 possible combinations as I *think* it'll be 6!

Comment: @JonRB It is a puzzle. Inputs and outputs are given and we have to find the permutations of the 6 gates in the 6 positions which, given the inputs, provide the desired outputs. So it is just a brute force search for all possible combinations/permutations.